# Inversify container is undefined in the runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

Cannot get an instance from the inversify container when I try to execute getNamed().  The container is well defined, typescript does not complain, I can see that the type of the import is "Container"; however, in the runtime container is undefined.

I'm binding UserRepo class as shown below, and exporting the container as "Registry"

```
container.bind<Repository>('Repository').to(UserRepo).inSingletonScope().whenTargetNamed('User');
.
.
.
export { container as Registry };
```

```
import { Registry } from '../registry';
import { UserRepo } from '../repositories/userRepository';
const userRepo: UserRepo = Registry.getNamed('Repository', 'User'); // throws an error
```

The error I get is

```
uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'getNamed' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNamed' of undefined
```

I am executing the same code, for a different class, in the root of my application, and it works. It would be great if anyone can point out where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Are you using `reflect-metadata`? Maybe, if you're importing that package inside of `../registry` and importing that file multiple time, this could be the problem, since `reflect-metadata` should only be imported once.

Comment: I am using reflect-metadata. I was importing it in the registry.  Tried moving it to the entry point of my application, did not help.  I think the problem is because registry is not ready for some reason when I start the application.  If I try to call getNamed() in a function, which gets called only when my server receives a request, everything works. So I feel like it is an async issue, but I don't know how to resolve it.